# Make Layer from Group Layer Result in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I want to use the ModelBuilder with the following scenario. I use the tool "Trace Geometric Network" in the model, and therefore receive a group layer as the output. I want to use the trace information of ONE layer from this output later in the model. So I have to make a new layer with this ONE layer, but I can't connect the group layer to the "Make Feature Layer" tool.

Would you know how to make a new layer, which is part of a group layer in the ModelBuilder?

Comment: The Help page indicates you should use Select Data with Make Feature Layer to pull a single layer out of the group layer.